# Android, Jackson KitKat incompatability: missing classes

Tags: android, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.8.5 with Retrofit in an android app that compiles with java 1.8 and runs well on 21+.
I am trying for at least Kitkat coverage (19) but am getting dalvik runtime error:

```
dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.Transient', referenced from
method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl.findTransient
```

Indeed,  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl requires these 3 classes which were added in 1.7:

```
import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;
import java.beans.Transient;
import java.nio.file.Path;
```

Is there a way to include them at runtime on a 4.4.4 device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proguard was stripping out the three classes that are required for android versions prior to L to work with Jackson now
https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/pull/142